# Fedora window manager list

Tags: fedora, window-manager

At the login screen of newer releases of fedora there is a drop down menu "session" where you can choose the window managers you have installed. gnome, mate, gnome classic, XBMC. etc How can I put an unofficial window manager there? Normally they appear there after install, I'm assuming there is a folder or something with those launchers in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you're right.

A new GDM Desktop Entry needs to go in /usr/share/xsessions.  You can look at what's already there to help create your own (cp & modify), or you could read some of the documentation that will help you create your new unofficial_window_manager.desktop file.  Perhaps you already have a unofficial_window_manager.desktop file and just need to drop it in the directory.

[GDM Session Configuration](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.8/configuration.html.en#sessionconfig)

[www/ Specifications/ desktop-entry-spec](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/)

Comment: For Wayland, the folder is `/usr/share/wayland-sessions`.